# Targeted downvotes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

A lot of my questions have got downvotes recently:
[image: Questions]
Note that most of these questions are not active ones: I had asked most of them more than a week ago and had accepted answers for the same. One or two downvotes is understandable, but getting 5-6 of them on my questions in the span of two days seems odd, almost like a single person is going around downvoting these things.

**Could the downvoter please clarify any mistakes he found in these questions**? If not, could the moderators please shed light on who is doing the downvoting? Any (constructive) criticism will be taken into account and I will try to improve on it in future posts.

Comment: If/when the SE bot detects systematic voting (up or down) sometimes reversals happen quickly, sometimes it takes a while. Apparently random votes or vote storms happen from time to time.

Comment: I once down-voted an answer because I was looking at it on the phone, touched the down-button by accident and realized it only a day later. I get that in your case it was more systematic, but I am just saying that in general, there is a certain randomness to it all.

Comment: I'm afraid the cause is not some "Targeted downvotes" but various issues with your questions and relatively frequent downvoting on the site. While some downvotes may be really random and not for any good reason, you should try to go more for quality then quantity there. Getting 1-2 downvotes a day means one day you won't get any and another you get six. IIRC only one or two of these^ was mine, but my general feeling is you make some surprising mix of rather"advanced" and *very* basic questions, and the second thing is often a reason for downvote.

Comment: I don't mean to discourage you from asking, and think that soon enough you'll get a hold on what may be too broad or open ended or another issue, it's only natural in the beginnings :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Mithoron. I'll work on the basic part of the question a bit more from now on before posting.

Comment: Update: It looks like you are getting [some downvotes lately](https://imgur.com/abbXFSB), I am sure you've noticed that. IMO, the downvotes are eerily targeted because the downvotes were to 3 answers and 1 question of yours which had a negative score (before the downvote barrage that to in a short span of time). If problem still persist and you are getting downvotes in a eerie pattern, feel free to contact the support via email.

Comment: @NilayGhosh yes, I did notice that. I've chosen to ignore it for now though; I'm just letting them pass as genuine downvotes on poor questions/answers.

Comment: It hurts when someone downvotes your question/answers without criticizing/commenting. That being said, don't let these bother you, keep up your good work and you'll see your reputation soaring : )

Answer (score 11):

> If not, could the moderators please shed light on who is doing the downvoting?

No we can't; if we could, we wouldn't. Voting is private, and if the user casting votes did not want to clarify why, then that's perfectly within the workings of stack exchange.

There are algorithms in place that protect everyone from targeted voting (up and down). If they didn't kick in (they didn't), it's not severe enough to be caught automatically. I wouldn't call six votes a large enough sample to make much of in the first place. If this trend continues, however, please contact support via email. They have more insight into the page and can investigate deeper.

I know getting down votes can be discouraging, especially when in a small time frame, and especially when you don't know what is wrong. Don't let that get you down. Most, of not all, of us have gotten down votes without reason. For myself I found ignoring them the best option.

Comment: Thanks for the kind comments :D I will keep an eye out and contact support if this continues, but it doesn't look like I'm getting any more downvotes.

Comment: I have reached out to support. Got some downvotes on what I believe are good questions (and quite a few before that on bad questions, see the comments on the question). Waiting for them to reach back to me. cc @NilayGhosh